# JavaScript - click responding after one extra click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a drop-down list using CSS and JavaScript.

```js
document.querySelector('.dropdown-btn').addEventListener("click", function() {
  let list = document.getElementById("project-list");
  if (list.style.display === "none") {
    list.style.display = "inline-block";
  } else {
    list.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
#project-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="projects">Projects
    <button class="dropdown-btn">Show<i class="fas fa-angle-double-down"></i></button>
    <br>
    <ul id="project-list">
      <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">World</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can try it [here](https://codepen.io/vyom-yadav/pen/JjNGeKa). It responds after one extra click, but I am unable to figure out the reason. I am learning the front-end. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `list.style.display` is an empty string the first time you click the button. You need to check for that, as well:

```js
document.querySelector('.dropdown-btn').addEventListener("click", function() {
  let list = document.getElementById("project-list");

  if (!list.style.display || list.style.display === "none") {
    list.style.display = "inline-block";
  } else {
    list.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
#project-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="projects">Projects
    <button class="dropdown-btn">Show<i class="fas fa-angle-double-down"></i></button>
    <br>
    <ul id="project-list">
      <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">World</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not really, the css `none` you set can't be retrieved through JavaScript. Accessing that `display` value gets/sets in in the DOM, not in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to respond after the second click, because the `list.style.display` is an empty string when you first click it.

Surprised? The CSS rule applies to the element, but it doesn't apply to the JavaScript object.

To get the actual style of the element (including CSS rules and inline styles), you can use `getComputedStyle()`.

For example:

```js
document.querySelector('.dropdown-btn').addEventListener("click", function() {
  let list = document.getElementById("project-list");
  let style = getComputedStyle(list)
  if (style.display === "none") {
    list.style.display = "inline-block";
  } else {
    list.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```